# My MacBook Pro does not show Ubuntu USB while holding Alt/Option Key

Tags: 12.04, boot, usb-drive, macbook-pro

I'm unable to see my newly created 12.04 in the list after holding alt/option when restarting my MacBook Pro

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue when I followed the steps from [Ubuntu's site](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx). It worked right away when I used [UNetbootin for OSX](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/).